# MongoDB: Setting in a document with a nested document with nested arrays with nested documents

Tags: mongodb

I want to $set a field in all documents within all arrays within a document within a document. 
Basically, I want to do this

```
{$set : {'documentname.*anyandallstrings*.*anyandallnum*.fieldname' : value}}
```

A sample of the document schema is here

```
{
"_id" : "abc123",
"documenttoset" : {
    "arrayname" : [ 
        {
            "fieldname" : "fieldvalue"
            //i want to add fields here,
        }, 
        {
            "fieldname2" : "fieldvalue2",
            "fieldname3" : "fieldvalue3"
            //here,
        }
    ],
    "arrayname2" : [ 
        {
            "fieldname4" : "fieldvalue4",
            "fieldname5" : "fieldvalue5",
            "fieldname6" : "fieldvalue6",
            //and here. 

        }
    ]
},
}
```

It should add the field in question to these nested documents, and must be scalable if there are more documents and more arrays.

I did not design the schema.

How is this done? I am not sure if it is even possible.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your document's schema? I think it would be more clear.

Comment: @dgiugg just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this is to iterate through the documents and update each field individually.

```
import pymongo

c = pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient(host='localhost')

db = c.local

cursor = db.test.find()

for q in cursor:
    dic = q
    for f in dic:
        field = dic[f]
        if(f != '_id'):
            for a in field:
                array = field[a]

                for d in array:
                    d['newfield'] = 'value'
```

After you've done that you just have to find the document in question and update it.

```
db.test.update({'_id':'abc123'}, dic)
```

You'll have to use a driver (obviously). I like using python and pymongo, but there are tons of drivers out there.

If this is a db admin job I would recommend using pymongo within the python shell.

Hope it helps!!